# Django ORM Exclusive ORs

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have an issue with my Django ORM query.

This query:

```py
Ticket.objects.filter(
    Q(change_personal_data__personal_data__number=number,
      change_personal_data__is_active=True)
)
```

produces the following query:

```sql
SELECT "tickets_ticket"."id" FROM "tickets_ticket"
INNER JOIN "tickets_changepersonaldata" ON ("tickets_ticket"."id" = "tickets_changepersonaldata"."ticket_id")
INNER JOIN "tickets_personal" ON ("tickets_changepersonaldata"."personal_data_id" = "tickets_personal"."id")
WHERE ("tickets_personal"."number" = 'xxxxxxxx' AND "tickets_changepersonaldata"."is_active" = True);
```

and this one:

```py
Ticket.objects.filter(Q(Q(personal_data__number=number) & ~Q(change_personal_data__is_active=True)))
```

produces this:

```sql
SELECT "tickets_ticket"."id" FROM "tickets_ticket"
INNER JOIN "tickets_personal" ON ("tickets_ticket"."personal_data_id" = "tickets_personal"."id")
WHERE ("tickets_personal"."number" = 'xxxxxxxx' AND
NOT ("tickets_ticket"."id" IN (SELECT U1."ticket_id" AS Col1 FROM "tickets_changepersonaldata" U1 WHERE U1."is_active" = True)));
```

but when I combine them (with OR condition) within 1 queryset

```
Ticket.objects.filter(
        Q(
            Q(change_personal_data__personal_data__number=number,
              change_personal_data__is_active=True) |
            Q(
                Q(personal_data__number=number) &
                ~Q(change_personal_data__is_active=True)
            )
        )
)
```

I get:

```sql
SELECT "tickets_ticket"."id" FROM "tickets_ticket"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tickets_changepersonaldata" ON ("tickets_ticket"."id" = "tickets_changepersonaldata"."ticket_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tickets_personal" ON ("tickets_changepersonaldata"."personal_data_id" = "tickets_personal"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tickets_personal" T4 ON ("tickets_ticket"."personal_data_id" = T4."id")
WHERE
("tickets_personal"."number" = 'xxxxxxxx' AND "tickets_changepersonaldata"."is_active" = True)
OR
(T4."number" = 'xxxxxxxx'
AND
NOT ("tickets_ticket"."id" IN (SELECT U1."ticket_id" AS Col1 FROM "tickets_changepersonaldata" U1 WHERE (U1."is_active" = True AND U1."id" = ("tickets_changepersonaldata"."id")))));
```

but I need to have this SQL:

```sql
SELECT "tickets_ticket"."id" FROM "tickets_ticket"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tickets_changepersonaldata" ON ("tickets_ticket"."id" = "tickets_changepersonaldata"."ticket_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tickets_personal" ON ("tickets_changepersonaldata"."personal_data_id" = "tickets_personal"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tickets_personal" T4 ON ("tickets_ticket"."personal_data_id" = T4."id")
WHERE
("tickets_personal"."number" = 'xxxxxxxx' AND "tickets_changepersonaldata"."is_active" = True)
OR
(T4."number" = 'xxxxxxxx'
AND
NOT ("tickets_ticket"."id" IN (SELECT U1."ticket_id" AS Col1 FROM "tickets_changepersonaldata" U1 WHERE (U1."is_active" = True))));
```

How to achieve that?

The diff is in the last line:

```
AND U1."id" = ("tickets_changepersonaldata"."id")
```

I want to get rid of it.